# requests: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I installed the `requests` package last week and it worked fine.. Until this morning. I coded this and I got the `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'` message:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Montreal%2C+QC')
```

I read in other posts that it might be because I have more than one `requests` packages installed.
When I code `print(dir(requests))` I get two lists..:

```
['__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__',
'requests']

['__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__',
'requests']
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Sylvain

Comment: and what does `requests.__file__` give you?

Comment: You called your script requests.py

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it possible that you named your script `requests.py` or that you have a similarly named file in the same directory?

Comment: That's it Alec! I created a requests.py file. I deleted it and now it works.